# SF book where an alien race transports a human to set up trade with other races

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I read a small portion of a book where the plot revolves around a human who is being transported by an alien race to set up trade with other alien races.  I have been trying to remember the title/author for many years.

Comment: Welcome to the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, Andrew. It will help us identify your novel if you give us as much information as you can remember. Aliens, names, races, technology, story plot, how long ago you read it, if you can remember when it was published, any distinctive technology or characters. All of these things help us try to identify your novel.

Comment: Was the protagonist a dentist?

Comment: More information really would help, but the stories that come to my mind are the [Chanur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chanur_novels#Plot_summaries) novels by  C. J. Cherryh.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to go way out on a limb here in that this sounds like the 2001 novel "First Contract" by Greg Costikyan.  The protagonist loses millions during an alien first contact with Earth.  He manages to hitch a rides with aliens and a science fiction author to an intergalactic trade conference to convince the aliens to open up trade with backwater Earth.

[Fantastic Fiction Review](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/c/greg-costikyan/first-contract.htm)

[InfinityPlus book review](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/nonfiction/firstcontract.htm)

Synopsis:
The market is up. The product is selling. The company (and the CEO) are about to make even more money. Unttil the aliens land.

Review:

In First Contract, Costikyan has resurrected an idea from some long-forgotten shoebox, a novella originally titled "Sales Reps from the Stars." A savvy CEO, a power-suit-wearing, proper Indian businessman by the name of Johnson Mukerjii, gets screwed by an alien invasion. The ETs want to do business, except we're the Aztecs and they're the Spaniards, and we can kiss our gold good-bye. But Mukerjii, after losing everything--his millions, his San Jose manse, his leggy wife--figures out how to beat the aliens at their own game in a characteristically Costikyan way: by producing exports in the form of cheesy, shoddily constructed spaceship beverage accoutrements:

"Made in Japan," "Made in Taiwan," and now--I gestured grandly--"Made on Earth."

Answer (score 3):

Reminds me of CJ Cherryh, "The Pride of Chanur" where Tully is the remaining crewmember of a captured merchant spaceship from Earth who escapes his captors and stows away on a spaceship owned by a more peaceful bunch of aliens. He's pretty much the lone human in the book.

But he's not so much trying to set up trade as he is seen (among the machinations so common in Cherryh's books) to represent a vast new set of customers.